# groupcache get group from a different main instance will it work?

Tags: go, caching

```
func NewGroupCacheHandler(cfg *viper.Viper) (*GroupCacheHandler, error) {
    var (
        endpoint     = cfg.GetString("storage.kv.groupcache.endpoint")
        ports        = cfg.GetStringSlice("storage.kv.groupcache.ports")
        cacheTTL     = cfg.GetInt64("storage.kv.groupcache.cacheTTL")
        cacheServers []*http.Server
        group        *groupcache.Group
    )

    var kvHandler KVHandler
    var getterFunc groupcache.GetterFunc
    kvType := cfg.GetString("storage.kv.groupcache.db")
    getterFunc = func(ctx context.Context, key string, dest groupcache.Sink) error {

        resp, err := kvHandler.Get(key)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if resp == nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("key not found in etcd: %s", key)
        }
        jsonResp, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
        dest.SetBytes(jsonResp, time.Now().Add(time.Duration(cacheTTL)*time.Minute))
        return nil

    }
    switch kvType {
    case "etcd":
        etcdHandler, err := NewEtcdHandler(cfg)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        kvHandler = etcdHandler
    case "badger":
        badgerHandler, err := NewBadgerHandler(cfg)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        kvHandler = badgerHandler
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported kvType: %s", kvType)
    }

    pool := groupcache.NewHTTPPool("")
    for _, port := range ports {
        pool.Set("http://" + endpoint + ":" + port)
        server := &http.Server{
            Addr:    endpoint + ":" + port,
            Handler: pool,
        }
        cacheServers = append(cacheServers, server)
        go func(srv *http.Server) {
            log.Printf("Serving cache server %s \n", srv.Addr)
            if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }(server)
    }

    group = groupcache.GetGroup("data")
    if group == nil {
        fmt.Println("Error getting group from groupcache:")
        group = groupcache.NewGroup("data", 3000000, getterFunc)
    }

    handler := &GroupCacheHandler{
        KVHandler: kvHandler,
        Group:     group,
        cacheTTL:  cacheTTL,
    }

    return handler, nil
}
```

I am running multiple main instances that use this function what I need is to be able to reach cache instance from another instance the problem is when am doing getgroup it doesn't work anyone have a solution?